# Create an event log from an excel file by turning columns into repeated rows

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel sheet like the following:

```
ID  Arrival Passed      Berthing Date       UnBerthing Date     Departure Passed 
1   13/05/2017 15:30    13/05/2017 16:00    31/05/2017 20:44    31/05/2017 
2   15/05/2017 16:56    15/05/2017 17:15    16/05/2017 00:00    16/05/2017 
3   20/05/2017 09:54    20/05/2017 10:26    20/05/2017 18:07    20/05/2017 
4   24/05/2017 16:09    24/05/2017 16:35    25/05/2017 01:03    25/05/2017 
5   29/05/2017 10:30    29/05/2017 10:45    29/05/2017 17:33    29/05/2017
```

I need this in the following format:

```
ID  Event       Time
1   Arrival     13/05/2017 15:30
1   Berth       13/05/2017 16:00
1   UnBerth     31/05/2017 20:44
1   Departure   31/05/2017 20:58
2   Arrival     15/05/2017 16:56
2   Berth       15/05/2017 17:15
2   UnBerth     16/05/2017 00:00
2   Departure   16/05/2017 00:04
```

etc

I've searched the web and this site(youtube...), but with no right answer, i've tried the transpose function and pivot table, but i couldn't make it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks you.

Comment: `INDEX` and `MATCH`, how have you tried so far, can you post what you have done.

Comment: If you need to update your question, you need to edit your original question (not add to it as an answer). You can leave a comment on any answers to say that you have updated the question. It has been flagged for review. Also please provide matching data in your question so we can help more effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your dataset is in range `A2:E6`.

For getting ID:

`=INDEX($A$2:$E$6,CEILING(ROWS($A$1:A1)/4,1),1)`

For getting Event:

`=CHOOSE(MOD(ROWS($A$1:A1)-1,4)+1,"Arrival","Berth","Unberth","Departure")`

For getting Time:

`=INDEX($A$2:$E$6,CEILING(ROWS($A$1:A1)/4,1),MOD(ROWS($A$1:A1)-1,4)+2)`

and then copy down until you get error.